# Sum Columns on Conditional Statement in r

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, lag

I want to sum the 3 previous columns of var1_stat and var2_stat individually based on the following conditions: a1 is a match, `event_id` is desc order, and the `entry != 0`.

[image: example]

I'm uncertain how to write this code conditionally, so my hack was to just lag the variables individually and sum them up. Since I can't skip zero's and still maintain my desired info, I have added a count of the instances where the var's don't equal 0. I'll later divide the sum by this number.

**Moving forward:** is there a more elegant way to write this code so I don't have to list lags for each variable? Also, is there a way to find the previous 3 column instances where the var is not equal to zero.

```
library(janitor)
library(dplyr)

a1 <- c('adam', 'adam', 'adam', 'adam', 'megan', 'megan', 'megan','jen', 'jen', 'jen', 'jen')
event_id <- as.numeric(c('1', '2', '3', '6', '2', '4', '5', '1', '2', '4', '6'))
var1_stat <- as.numeric(c('3.2', '2.1', '2.7', '0','2','3.3', '1.1', '0', '4.1', '2.2','3.1'))
var2_stat <- as.numeric(c('3.4', '3', '0','1.7', '1.2', '3', '0','3.3', '2.1', '3.2', '0'))
test_ex <- data.frame(a1, event_id, var1_stat, var2_stat)


test_ex3 <- test_ex %>%
  group_by(a1) %>%
  mutate(var1_lag = lag(var1_stat),
         var1_lag2 = lag(var1_stat,2),
         var1_lag3 = lag(var1_stat,3 )
  ) %>% 
  mutate(var2_lag = lag(var2_stat),
         var2_lag2 = lag(var2_stat,2),
         var2_lag3 = lag(var2_stat,3)
         ) %>%
  ungroup()

test_ex3$var1_sum3 <- rowSums(test_ex3[,5:7], na.rm = TRUE)
test_ex3$var1_count3 <- rowSums(test_ex3[,5:7] != 0, , na.rm = TRUE)
test_ex3$var2_sum3 <- rowSums(test_ex3[,8:10], na.rm = TRUE)
test_ex3$var2_count3 <- rowSums(test_ex3[,8:10] != 0, , na.rm = TRUE)


test_ex3 <- test_ex3 %>%
  select(-var1_lag,-var1_lag2, -var1_lag3, -var2_lag,-var2_lag2, -var2_lag3)
```

Comment: Generally summing previous `n` values is called a "rolling sum" or a "windowed sum". If you search for "rolling sum in R" or "rolling sum with dplyr" you'll find lots of resources. The `rollapply` package provides lots of utilities for doing rolling calculations. The `slider` package is newer and is part of the `tidyverse`. The skipping 0s, however, is an unusual requirement so will require some special handling that is probably not baked in to these packages.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas - This is a helpful alternative to perform sum functions. It is also helpful to know that there isn't necessarily an easy solution on the conditional statement component when performing sum functions.

Comment: The best way I can think of to ignore 0s is to filter your data to drop 0s, run a standard n = 3 rolling sum, and then join the results back to the original data. You could write a little function for it and then apply it to each column in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
df %>%
  group_by(a1) %>%
  arrange(event_id) %>%
  mutate(newvar = sum(df[var1_stat !=0 & var2_stat !=0], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mike - I couldn't get the code to work. Ideally, my code will get the sum of the last 3 instances of var1_stat, with the variable not equalling 0, in it's own stat and the last 3 instances of var2_stat (!=0) in it's own stat. I didn't include the code for var2_stat in my op just to avoid redundnacy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing some more posts and taking @GregorThomas advice for `rollsum`, I was able to write this code which is signficantly cleaner than my original. That said, still can't find something that does a rolling sum with conditional filters. ie get the sum of the last 3 instances where the var doesn't equal 0.

```
test_ex3 <- test_ex %>%
  group_by(a1) %>%
  mutate(var1_sum3_u= lag(rollsum(var1_stat,2, align = "right", fill = NA))) %>%
  mutate(var1_count3_u= lag(rollsum(var1_stat != 0, 2, align = "right", fill = NA)))
```